# windows admin command prompt find file by name

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, search

I know I have a file named Foo.bar somewhere on my Windows computer. I want to open an admin command prompt, and with a few commands, find the file. Hopefully without disabling UAC, opening other UIs or anything obnoxious like that.

Comment: Relevant: [Find files across all drives using Powershell](http://serverfault.com/q/16185)

Comment: [Find Files on Local Drives with Whereis.ps1](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/find-files-local-drives-whereisps1)

Comment: Command prompt != PowerShell.

Comment: @JaggenSWE Don't be so pedantic. You can run powershell scripts from a `cmd` shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start off in the root of the drive and run a

`dir Foo.bar /b/s`

Should be sufficient.

Comment: And if I have more than one disk drive this is a bit inconvenient :/

Comment: In that case, Powershell is the way to go, or create a program that does the thing you're after.

Comment: If we are stuck to the incredible cmd, then this can be exploited:

for /f "skip=1 delims=" %d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do @echo.%d

Comment: @GombaiSándor Indeed. I was working on my answer when you posted your comment. The tricky bit was removing the blank lines from the `wmic` output ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### I have a file named Foo.bar somewhere on my Windows computer

The following batch file will search across all drives.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1" %%d in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  dir %%d\%1 /b /s
  )
endlocal
```

Usage:

```
test Foo.bar
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.